# Which Design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I have a program which models manufacturing process. In each stage of the process , objects are created. Specific objects can be created only in certain stage . The objects created in later stage, are using the objects created in earlier stages i.e output of previous stage is input to later stage.Which design pattern to use to model this behavior? I am not recognizing in this, any patterns that I am aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about Pipeline ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (Wikipedia) building a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

More resources [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BuilderPattern) (c2com) and [here](http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/builder_pattern.htm) (Java).

In general, always take a look at the most popular [patterns list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)), and use them as **guidelines**, never allow a pattern to [*pattern* your thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) :>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can model you application on a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)?